# Как каждое значение переменной можно поместить в список?

Tags: python

Переменная постоянно меняет значения.
Код:

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    print(x)
```

Вывод:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Как каждое значение переменной можно поместить в список?

Comment: my_list = [x for x in range(10)]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это основы, ради которых стОит минимально почитать литературу или загуглить за 30 сек, а не постить вопросом на руСО

Comment: `my_list = list(range(10))` чё мудрить-то

Comment: почитайте https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант

```
list = []
for x in range(0, 10):
    list.append(x)
print(list)
```

Вывод:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

С использованием list comprehension

```
list = [i for i in range(10)]
print(list)
```

Вывод:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]