# Как занести в список переменную, значение которой постоянно меняется

Tags: python

Есть переменная, её значения постоянно меняются.

Пример:

```
import random

asd = ['one', 'two', 'three']
while True:
    value = random.choice(asd)
    print(value)
```

Переменная типа str

Как можно занести в список каждое их значений?

Comment: На самом деле для каких-то задач список и не нужен, если значения всё-равно случайные, то зачем их хранить, лучше экономить память и "генерировать" такое значение каждый раз заново.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как каждое значение переменной можно поместить в список?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1283724/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 2):

Понятно. Слово "список" знаем. А методы списка учить (даже читать о них) необязательно. Ответ на ваш вопрос - используйте метод .append() и читайте книжки, а не бегайте на форум за каждой запятой.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял.